# Creating nonce account as a durable transaction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, durable-nonce

Is there a way to create a nonce account as a durable transaction? The use case is for fireblocks users who might timeout on conventional transactions, so we would like to use durable transactions. However, there is still the issue of creating the nonce account for the fireblocks account in the first place, which would also time out. What is the optimal way to deal with this issue, or a way to send the nonce account creation transaction as a durable transaction as well, so users can use the same flow?

Answer (score 1):

The best choice is probably to create the nonce account in a regular transaction then use it as needed for your durable transactions. The creation of a nonce account is unlikely to time out.

Comment: Hi, the issue with that is if the people are timing out on regular transactions, how will they be able to create the nonce account?